# Redirect specific traffic on bridge to different port

Tags: iptables, bridge

I've a device with 2 physical network interfaces, let's call it `A`. I connected `A` to a second device `B` and a network.

`B - A - network`

Now I want to redirect all traffic from `A` on port 502 to port 5020 of `A`, also local traffic. But I can't get any further then redirecting all traffic from port 502 to port 5020 of `A`. So `B:502` ends up at `A:5020`. But I only want `A:502` redirected to `A:5020`.

This is how I built the bridges:

```
brctl addbr br0 
brctl stp br0 on

brctl addif br0 eth0 
brctl addif br0 eth1

ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0
```

I've used these `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 502 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5020
```

And

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 502 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5020
```

Comment: Why don't use `-i <interface>` or `-s <source>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching specific interface in `iptables` rules use `-i` option, and you have to specify the table you want to add rule to like `nat` table:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <eth> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 502 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5020
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -i <eth> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 502 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5020
```

Comment: And i had to run `sysctl  net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0` so packets traversing through the bridge are not sent to iptables.